# Scheme expression that takes in an s-expression exp and a variable x that returns the given number of sub expressions in exp that equal x

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

My code is currently as follows:

```
(define (count-occurrences exp x)
  (define (helper exp x result)     
    (if(null? exp)
       result
       (if(equal? (car exp) x)
          (helper(cdr exp) x (+ 1 result))
          (helper(cdr exp) x result)))
          )
       
     (helper exp x -1)
  )
```

The input to this program is of the form of (count-occurrences '( (* 5 3) (a (* 5 3) 3) ) 3)
Here we are trying to parse the expression in order to count the number of matches to 3 which should
be 2 however without flattening the list it will parse as (* 5 3) on the first recursive call and then (a (* 5 3) 3) on the second recursive call. A simple fix would be to flatten the list however if we call the same function with (*5 3) as x it will return 1 instead of 2 since flattening will remove parenthesis.
I guess my question is how can i iterate through a flattened version of the list for digit cases and how can i iterate into the nested sublists such as (* 5 3) in (a (* 5 3) 3)

I forgot to add this function is expected to be done recursively instead of iteratively and use of map foldl and foldr are forbidden

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the point of `(+ 0 result)`?  How is that different from `result`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Was meant to be (+ 1 result) to increment result

Comment: Doesn't `(helper (car exp))` need to be in there somewhere?

Comment: With `(count-occurrences '((* 5 3) (a (* 5 3) 3)) 3)` you have the expression `((* 5 3) (a (* 5 3) 3))`, in which I count three occurrences of `3`. "_... count the number of matches to 3 which should be 2._" How do you come up with two?

Comment: What should `(count-occurrences '(let ((x '(x))) (car x)) 'x)` return?  Which of the `x`'s are supposed to be "subexpressions"?

Answer (score 1):

So a good way (or a way I like) to do this sort of search-for-something-in-something-else is to use an agenda: an agenda is simply 'the things I need to remember to search later after I've finished searching this thing'.  In other words an agenda is a reified stack, really: by using an explicit agenda you can have a purely iterative program which searches a recursively-defined structure.  Of course, you could just use the implicit stack provided by the language, but using an agenda is kind of nice I think.

In this case I assume that what you are trying to do is to search for something in a set of nested lists.  And the way you use an agenda to do this is that, when you get to something which is a cons, you search its first element while putting all the other elements on the agenda.

Here is an implementation of that.  However, before you hand it, or something like it, in as the answer, note that *it is buggy*.  The bug is slightly subtle: to find it you'll need to think of all the things you might want to search for and why you might find more of one particular thing than you should.  Then it's easy to fix.

```
(define (count-occurrences expression thing (same? equal?))
  ;; THIS IS BUGGY!
  (define (co-loop current count more)
    (cond
      [(same? current thing)
       ;; found it: increment and count
       (punt (+ count 1) more)]
      [(cons? current)
       ;; search the first element & remember to searth the rest
       (co-loop (first current) count (cons (rest current) more))]
      [else
       ;; Punt
       (punt count more)]))
  (define (punt count more)
    ;; If there is more, search it, otherwise we're done
    (if (empty? more)
        count
        (co-loop (first more) count (rest more))))
  (co-loop expression 0 '()))
```